# Is geometric Brownian motion stationary?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I was just wondering if the solution to
$$dX(t) = \mu X(t) dt + \sigma X(t) dB(t)$$
gives a stationary process for any $\mu,\sigma$ and what the distribution would be.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: With this very likely to be a homework, please share what you know, and what you had already attempted.

Answer (score 5):

The form of the GBM is
$$ X(t) = X(0)\exp{\left( \left(\mu - \frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)t + \sigma B(t) \right)} $$
It is easy to calculate the expectation and the variance of GBM (it is just use the formula for the moment generating function of a normal random variable). So we have
$$ E(X(t)) = X(0)e^{\mu t}$$
and
$$ Var(X(t)) = X(0)^2 e^{2\mu t}(e^{\sigma^2 t} - 1).$$
So unless we have the trivial case $\mu = \sigma = 0$ the process cannot be stationary because in that case, $X(t)$ would have the same distribution regardless of $t$, and so the all their moments would not depend on $t$; but here it is not the case.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is quite clear now. Is it then possible to make it stationary by letting $\mu$ and $\sigma$ depend on $t$ in the right way? e.g. $\mu (t) = \frac{1}{t}$ and $\sigma^2 (t) = \frac{1}{t}$? But it is strage to me, because I thought one needed to have stationarity in order to estimate the parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$.

Comment: In these notes you can find the general form for $\mu$ and $\sigma$ non constant. It is clear from there that your guess will not work.
http://web.mst.edu/~bohner/fim-10/fim-chap3.pdf .